# WCF Client Sign Soap Message with Smart Card

Tags: c#, web-services, wcf, soap, sign

I have forms application with service reference by using CustomBinding for signing soap request (Only need soap body will be signed). If I try to sign request with private key included pfx wcf client succesfully sign Basic256Sha256Rsa15.

Succesfull case below:

```
private CustomBinding GetCustomHttpBinding()
        {
            CustomBinding binding = new CustomBinding();
            // Open and Close = 20s 
            binding.OpenTimeout = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 20);
            binding.CloseTimeout = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 20);
            // Send and Receive = 300s
            binding.SendTimeout = new TimeSpan(0, 5, 0);
            binding.ReceiveTimeout = new TimeSpan(0, 5, 0);
            // ++ Setting security binding ++
            var param = new X509SecurityTokenParameters();
            param.X509ReferenceStyle = X509KeyIdentifierClauseType.IssuerSerial;
            param.ReferenceStyle = SecurityTokenReferenceStyle.Internal;
            param.InclusionMode = SecurityTokenInclusionMode.AlwaysToRecipient;
            param.RequireDerivedKeys = false;

            var userNameToken = new UserNameSecurityTokenParameters();
            userNameToken.InclusionMode = SecurityTokenInclusionMode.AlwaysToRecipient;

            var securityElement = new AsymmetricSecurityBindingElement();

            securityElement.EnableUnsecuredResponse = true;
            securityElement.IncludeTimestamp = true;
            securityElement.RecipientTokenParameters = new X509SecurityTokenParameters(X509KeyIdentifierClauseType.IssuerSerial, SecurityTokenInclusionMode.Never);
            securityElement.InitiatorTokenParameters = new X509SecurityTokenParameters(X509KeyIdentifierClauseType.IssuerSerial, SecurityTokenInclusionMode.AlwaysToRecipient);
            securityElement.DefaultAlgorithmSuite = SecurityAlgorithmSuite.Basic256Sha256Rsa15;
            securityElement.SecurityHeaderLayout = SecurityHeaderLayout.Strict;
            securityElement.SetKeyDerivation(false);
            securityElement.EndpointSupportingTokenParameters.Signed.Add(param);
            //securityElement.MessageProtectionOrder = MessageProtectionOrder.SignBeforeEncrypt;
            securityElement.MessageSecurityVersion = MessageSecurityVersion.WSSecurity11WSTrust13WSSecureConversation13WSSecurityPolicy12BasicSecurityProfile10;
            binding.Elements.Add(securityElement);


            // ++ Setting message encoding binding ++
            var encodingElement = new TextMessageEncodingBindingElement();
            encodingElement.MessageVersion = MessageVersion.Soap12;
            encodingElement.WriteEncoding = Encoding.UTF8;
            //encodingElement.MaxReadPoolSize = 50000000;
            //encodingElement.MaxWritePoolSize = 50000000;
            encodingElement.ReaderQuotas.MaxArrayLength = 50000000;
            encodingElement.ReaderQuotas.MaxStringContentLength = 50000000;

            binding.Elements.Add(encodingElement);

            // ++ Setting https transport binding ++
            var httpsElement = new HttpsTransportBindingElement();
            // Messagge buffer size
            httpsElement.MaxBufferSize = 50000000;
            httpsElement.MaxReceivedMessageSize = 50000000;
            httpsElement.MaxBufferPoolSize = 50000000;
            httpsElement.RequireClientCertificate = true;

            // Others
            httpsElement.UseDefaultWebProxy = true;
            binding.Elements.Add(httpsElement);

            return binding;
        }
```

And Service Sertificate set as

```
client.ClientCredentials.ClientCertificate.Certificate=cert;// From pfx file
client.ClientCredentials.ServiceCertificate.DefaultCertificate =serverCert;//from server certificate
```

I try to sign with my company smart card which is ACS38 smart card. If I use DefaultAlgotihmSuite Basic128 or Basic128Rsa15 then smartCard certificate succesfully sign body elements. I change algorihmsuite Basic256Sha256Rsa15 for requirement then I get KeySet does not exist. In this Smart Card have private key but WCF does not reach that private key.

Is there way to sign to Sign Soap Body with Sha256Rsa on SmartCard ?

Comment: Hi, Did you solve this problem or find any other solution?